# Source files not found for Kotlin convention packaging during JaCoCo report generation

Tags: testing, kotlin, report, code-coverage, jacoco

When setting up JaCoCo for a Kotlin project using the [Coding Conventions recommended directory structure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html) (putting files at the root if they share the same common package), the test coverage is calculated as expected **but** the report does not show the source files due to the following problem:

> Source file "com/example/controller/ExampleController.kt" was not
>   found during generation of report.

Is there a way to configure JaCoCo to pick up files from the correct directory such as in this example from `src/main/kotlin/controller` rather than `src/main/kotlin/com/example/controller` by perhaps providing a package prefix?

Comment: This appears to be a current limitation of JaCoCo due to the way it searches for these files (https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/blob/master/org.jacoco.report/src/org/jacoco/report/InputStreamSourceFileLocator.java), so I have created the following issue: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/939

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to create jacoco reports for an android java/kotlin project with custom paths.

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest']) {

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def javaClasses = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug/classes", excludes: fileFilter)
    def kotlinClasses = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)

    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src"

    sourceDirectories.setFrom(files([mainSrc]))
    classDirectories.setFrom(files([javaClasses, kotlinClasses]))
    executionData.setFrom(fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", includes: [
            "jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec"
    ]))
}
```

There is something weird with jacoco. I have in my project a custom path for source files. Something like this

```
src/example/org/implementation
```

With this type of path, you should only define in **Source Directories** the variable like this

```
def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src"
```

if you don't do this. Jacoco coverage will thrown some weird behaviors